# sfdx force:source:push error Push Failed. [XML parse error]

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, xml

I created lwc for embbeding in Community and push it to a scratch org by using the command "sfdx force:source:push" but I got the error:

```
Error parsing file: LWC Metadata Xml Parser: ParseError at [row,col]:[15,27]
Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="LWCinCommunity">
<apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<masterLabel>LWC in Community</masterLabel>
<targets>
  <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
  <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
  <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
      <property name="buttonText" type="String" default="defaultText" />
  </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I double checked the tags in the xml file so that all the start-tag and end-tag match.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you make sure you don't have any spaces after or before your tags, if at all there are spaces cli won't perform well.

Comment: Also, I don't think you want / at the end of your property line (4th from bottom)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that

Comment: Let me know if it worked or if the problem still exist

Comment: Sorry for late response. The problem still exsits.